# Javascript issue with fixed menu that responds to background container color

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a fixed menu that changes color when it appears over alternating/contrasting background containers.

I have two menus, one light and one dark. On the page I have a bunch of containers with a data attribute that is used to determine which type of menu (light or dark) should be visible when the fixed menu is over that container. Depending on where you are positioned on the page, a CSS clipping is applied to the menus and a masking effect is produced. This effect works when you go from alternating containers (i.e. light to dark, dark to light) but breaks when you go from like containers (i.e. light to light, dark to dark). I see that the issue occurs when the menu hits the bottom of the first container before it goes into the second container of the same background. What I would like is for the experience to be seamless and regardless of any combination of background container patterns used the logic will reflect correctly. I've tried putting a variation of conditionals to check previous, current, and next background patterns but I can't seem to find the correct combination to help my case.

(I apologize if my explanation is not more thorough. It's probably easier to see a working example of this.)

http://jsfiddle.net/picitelli/ce5yA/

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu dark">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Nav item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav item</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="menu light">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Nav item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav item</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="section light" data-menu="light"></div>
<div class="section dark" data-menu="dark"></div>
<div class="section light" data-menu="light"></div>
<div class="section light" data-menu="light"></div>
<div class="section light" data-menu="light"></div>
<div class="section light" data-menu="light"></div>
<div class="section light" data-menu="light"></div>
<div class="section dark" data-menu="dark"></div>
<div class="section light" data-menu="light"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var menuLight = $('.menu.light'),
    menuDark = $('.menu.dark'),
    useMenuLight = $('[data-menu="light"]'),
    useMenuDark = $('[data-menu="dark"]');

useMenuDark.each(function (){
    $(window).on('scroll',{ value: $(this), nav: menuDark }, clipping);
    $(window).on('load',{ value: $(this), nav: menuDark }, clipping);
    $(window).on('resize',{ value: $(this), nav: menuDark }, clipping);
});

useMenuLight.each(function (){
    $(window).on('scroll',{ value: $(this), nav: menuLight }, clipping);
    $(window).on('load',{ value: $(this), nav: menuLight }, clipping);
    $(window).on('resize',{ value: $(this), nav: menuLight }, clipping);
});

function clipping (event) {
    var elm = event.data.value,
        menu = event.data.nav,
        menuHeight = menu.outerHeight(true),
        offsetBottom = menu.offset().top + menuHeight, // complete offset height of the menu composed by OffsetTop + the outerHeight
        mainOffset = $(elm).offset().top, // top boundary of the container
        mainHeight = $(elm).outerHeight(true); // height of the container

    if(offsetBottom >= $(elm).offset().top) {
        topClip = mainOffset - $(window).scrollTop() - (menu.offset().top- $(window).scrollTop());
        botClip = topClip + mainHeight;

        menu.css('clip','rect('+topClip+'px,auto,'+botClip+'px,0)');

        if($(elm).prev().attr('data-menu') == 'light' && $(elm).attr('data-menu') == 'light') {
            menuLight.css('clip','rect(auto, auto, '+menuHeight+', auto)');
        }

    }
}
```

The only other working example I can find is on the web site Sketchin (http://www.sketchin.ch/). I grabbed the JS they were using and modified it slightly. The same issue occurs with their code but it isn't visible on their site because they use alternating patterns (light to dark). It only breaks when you switch the combination up (i.e. dark to dark to dark to light to light).

Any feedback/direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the following few modifications I think it works as you require.

http://jsfiddle.net/g32TY/

**html** - *added a few more sections*

```
    <div class="menu dark">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Nav item</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav item</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav item</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav item</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="menu light">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Nav item</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav item</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav item</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav item</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="section light" data-menu="light"></div>
<div class="section dark" data-menu="dark"></div>
<div class="section light" data-menu="light"></div>
<div class="section light" data-menu="light"></div>
<div class="section light" data-menu="light"></div>
<div class="section light" data-menu="light"></div>
<div class="section light" data-menu="light"></div>
<div class="section dark" data-menu="dark"></div>
<div class="section light" data-menu="light"></div>
<div class="section dark" data-menu="dark"></div>
<div class="section dark" data-menu="dark"></div>
<div class="section dark" data-menu="dark"></div>
<div class="section dark" data-menu="dark"></div>
<div class="section light" data-menu="light"></div>
```

**js**

- added the sections in sequence, so that the clipping takes place in order
- simplified the topClip a bit
- added a condition that checks if cliping of dark menu takes place, meaning it is required to show part of the dark menu, then also clip the light menu since clipping of dark without clipping of light has no effect at all. The light menu is always on top of dark
- generally check if the menu of this section is the same as the previous, in order to display the whole current menu

  ```
  var menuLight = $('.menu.light'),
  menuDark = $('.menu.dark'),
  useMenuLight = $('[data-menu="light"]'),
  useMenuDark = $('[data-menu="dark"]');
  var sections = $('[data-menu="light"],[data-menu="dark"]');

  sections.each(function () {
      $(window).on('scroll', {
          value: $(this)
      }, clipping);
      $(window).on('load', {
          value: $(this)
      }, clipping);
      $(window).on('resize', {
          value: $(this)
      }, clipping);
  });

  /*useMenuDark.each(function (){
      $(window).on('scroll',{ value: $(this), nav: menuDark }, clipping);
      $(window).on('load',{ value: $(this), nav: menuDark }, clipping);
      $(window).on('resize',{ value: $(this), nav: menuDark }, clipping);
  });

  useMenuLight.each(function (){
      $(window).on('scroll',{ value: $(this), nav: menuLight }, clipping);
      $(window).on('load',{ value: $(this), nav: menuLight }, clipping);
      $(window).on('resize',{ value: $(this), nav: menuLight }, clipping);
  });*/

  function clipping(event) {
      var elm = event.data.value,
          menu = elm.data('menu') === 'dark' ? menuDark : menuLight,
          menuHeight = menu.outerHeight(true),
          offsetBottom = menu.offset().top + menuHeight, // complete offset height of the menu composed by OffsetTop + the outerHeight
          mainOffset = $(elm).offset().top, // top boundary of the container
          mainHeight = $(elm).outerHeight(true); // height of the container

      if (offsetBottom >= mainOffset) {

          /*topClip = mainOffset - $(window).scrollTop() - (menu.offset().top- $(window).scrollTop());*/
          topClip = mainOffset - menu.offset().top;
          botClip = topClip + mainHeight;

          menu.css('clip', 'rect(' + topClip + 'px,auto,' + botClip + 'px,0)');
          if (menu === menuDark && $(elm).prev().data('menu') === 'light') {
              menuLight.css('clip', 'rect(' + 0 + 'px,auto,' + topClip + 'px,0)');
          }

          if ($(elm).prev().data('menu') === $(elm).data('menu')) {
              menu.css('clip', 'rect(auto, auto, ' + menuHeight + 'px, auto)');
          }
      }
  }
  ```

**css** *- untouched only posting the code for full reference*

```
.menu {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    left: 25px;
    padding: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -webkit-transform-style: flat;
}
.menu.dark {
    border-color: #000;
}
.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu a {
    color: #000;
}
.menu.light a {
    color: #fff;
}
.section {
    background: #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f8f8f8;
    height: 200px;
}
.section.dark {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Melc, this is perfect. Thank you so much!